# Populating a jagged char array in C from an unknow size list

Tags: c, arrays, string

**C program.** 
Will be compiled for linux 32 bit and windows 32 bit.

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
```

**Goal:**

To break a single char array that contains a list of songs into an multi-dimensional char array.
I will 'walk' this array and compare to another list then do 'work' on it such as delete songs or convert songs.

*buffer and song names are an unknown size.*

buffer contains “[playlist1]\n12345\n54321\n[playlist2]\n6789\n9876\n[playlist3]\nlonger song name\n”

*Need an array that contains the playlist # and the song name.*

112345

154321

26789

29876

3longer song name

array[0][0] should contain 1 (int 48)

array[0][2] should contain 2 (int 50)
...

**Work:**

I have counted the number of ‘\n’ to get an array total row size (ignore the “[playlist1] for now)

```
int array_length_all_songs = 0;
int index;
for (index = 0; index<plLength; index++)
{
    if (plBuffer[index] == '\n')
    {
        array_length_all_songs++;
    }
}
```

created an array of char type

```
char **array_playlist = calloc(array_length_all_songs, sizeof(char *));
```

populate array

```
char *token; /* "\x0a" == "\n"  */
char pl_num; /* remember a char is an int */
int array_length_working;
int song_name_length;
token = strtok(plBuffer,"\x0a");
while(token != NULL)
    /* set playlist number */
    if(strncmp(token,"[Playlist",9) == 0)
    {
        //printf("token: %s\n",token);
        pl_num = (unsigned char)token[9];
        //printf("pl: %c\n",pl_num);
    }
    else
    {
        array_length_working++;

        switch (pl_num)
        {
            case '1':
                if(strncmp(token,"[Playlist",9) != 0)
                {
                    song_name_length = strlen(token);
                    array_playlist[array_length_working] = calloc(song_name_length, sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(&array_playlist[array_length_working], token);

                }   
                break;
            case '2':
```

...

This code does not work because of pointer and type casting that I am struggling with.

```
strcpy(&array_playlist[array_length_working], token);
```

I have decided on this method of creating the array even though I must walk the buffer once to get a size.
I believe this method is called an *Iliffe vector*.

**Question:**

Am I approaching this all wrong or inefficient for memory limited computers?

if not...

I need to figure out how to copy the $token to the array $array[123][0]
since the token is an array of characters (int) must I copy each character or can I copy the whole ‘string’ into the new location?

I cannot create a variable on the fly $song1 so I cannot put the pointer of the song name into the array. Therefor I must copy the all the individual char to the array. $array[123][n++]. Right?

I have hacked around with programming for many years, but c programming is new to me and seems to require a different way of thinking, and I am still working on that.

I have read so many books and help questions but I seem to be going in circles.

If my approach is wrong an over view might help.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to concatenate each song title with the playlist number. Seeing as the playlist number must be a single digit (or you won't be able to distinguish playlist num and title), the max number of playlists is 10, which can be the index of each array of titles. So `array[3][0]` would be a pointer to the first song in playlist 3, etc.

Comment: BTW better not to hardcode the `newline` character, better to have `token = strtok(plBuffer, "\n");`

Comment: The max number of playlists will be 4. The user will select one of the four playlists or all of the play lists to do the 'work' on. I am thinking that I could do a 'if' against the first char (the playlist) to determine if work need to be done against that playlist.

Comment: I see the problem of using a jagged list though. Perhaps better to have an array of 4 `struct` which tells you the number of songs in each playlist, the max number that can be held, and an array of pointers to those titles, which can be `realloc`ed when they grow. Those pointers could be set by `strdup(token);`

Comment: So... What would be the 2nd song in playlist 3? Not array[3][1] because that would be the second char of the first song...

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that if I have an array of pointers to the song name I would need an variable for that name first? example song 5 on playlist 2 would need a variable to hold the name $song53...

Comment: It is getting too complicated without actually writing it for you. But I suggest an array of structs.

Comment: Thanks for your time. @Weather Vane. Please someone correct me if I am wrong, but In a struct one of the items would be an array of pointers to the song titles. Since I do not know the number of songs in the list I cannot create a spot for the song title array to point to... I need to grasp the theory first. Maybe not. Reading more.

Comment: You `malloc` the array first, and then `realloc` the array when you run out.

Comment: The code misses to allocate space for the C-"string"'s `0`-terminator here: `array_playlist[array_length_working] = calloc(song_name_length, sizeof(char));` *sigh* Use `array_playlist[array_length_working] = calloc(song_name_length + 1, 1);` `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition. Or do `array_playlist[array_length_working] = calloc(song_name_length + 1, sizeof  *array_playlist[array_length_working] ;`

Comment: Also you want to initialise `array_length_working` to `0` like this `int array_length_working = 0;` C does not necessarily do the for you,

Comment: And finally make all those `int` typed index-counters `size_t`, or, if not available, make them at least `unsigned`. You do not need negative indexes.

Comment: Thank you @alk for the corrections, and yes it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how you might build an array of play lists, each containing an array of song titles. It's not good practice to use global arrays, but for simplicity I have done so.

Each playlist has an array of song title pointers. When that array is full, it is extended. In practice the program would be more efficient with a larger value for `SONGS`.

I leave you to extract the data from file. Because the titles pointed to by your `token` will get overwritten, I used `strdup` or `_strdup` in MSVC (which calls `malloc`) to make a copy of each title. At the end of your program, you should iterate the array, to `free` each title's memory, and then `free` each pointer array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LISTS   4                   // number of play lists
#define SONGS   3                   // incremental number of songs per list

typedef struct {
    int numsongs;                   // number of songs in list
    int maxsongs;                   // maximum possible songs in list
    char **song;                    // base of array of pointers
} list_t;

list_t lib[LISTS] = { {0} };

void addsong(int listnum, char *title)
{
    list_t *ptr;
    char **arr;
    if (listnum < 1 || listnum > LISTS) {
        exit(1);                    // or other error checking
    }
    ptr = &lib[listnum-1];          // for convenience, and arrays are 0-based
    if (ptr->numsongs >= ptr->maxsongs) {
        // extend the song titles array
        arr = realloc(ptr->song, (ptr->maxsongs + SONGS) * sizeof(char*));
        if(arr == NULL) {
            exit(1);                // or other error checking
        }
        ptr->song = arr;            // new bigger array
        ptr->maxsongs += SONGS;     // more capacity
    }
    // save a pointer to a copy of the song title
    ptr->song[ ptr->numsongs ] = _strdup(title); 
    ptr->numsongs++;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;

    // add songs to playlists in random order
    addsong(2, "Song two/one");
    addsong(1, "Song one/one");
    addsong(4, "Song four/one");
    addsong(2, "Song two/two");
    addsong(1, "Song one/two");
    addsong(2, "Song two/three");
    addsong(2, "Song two/four");
    addsong(2, "Song two/five");
    addsong(1, "Song one/three");

    // show what we've got
    for(i=0; i<LISTS; i++) {
        printf("Playlist %d\n", i + 1);
        for(j=0; j<lib[i].numsongs; j++) {
            printf("   %s\n", lib[i].song[j]);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Playlist 1
   Song one/one
   Song one/two
   Song one/three
Playlist 2
   Song two/one
   Song two/two
   Song two/three
   Song two/four
   Song two/five
Playlist 3
Playlist 4
   Song four/one
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain something that I need to know.